# Hide loader hides as soon as shown

Tags: jquery

I am using simple jquery to show and hide a loader but because there is no callback as such its hiding as soon as showing. Here's the code, will comment it to explain flow:

```
$('#test img').click(function(e) { // image is clicked

    $('#loader').show(); // show loader
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);

    var url = $('input[name=url]').val();

    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    $('input[name=filter]').val(filter);

    // get image as a result of a call to another page
    $('#result').attr('src', 'index.php?url=' + url + '&filter=' + filter);

    $('#loader').hide(); // hide loader

});
```

As you can see the image is generated from a call to another php page, which outputs the image after processing like this:

```
$output = 'http://myurl.com/filter/' . $filename;
header('Location: ' . $output, TRUE, 301);
die;
```

Is there a way can I make a callback up so the loader loads when image clicked and then hides when other image created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$.ajax` and it's `success` callback

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'index.php?url=' + url + '&filter=' + filter,
    success: function (image) {
        $('#result').attr('src', image);
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding your loader in `$('#result').load()` event.

```
$('#test img').click(function(e) { // image is clicked

    $('#loader').show(); // show loader
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);

    var url = $('input[name=url]').val();

    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    $('input[name=filter]').val(filter);

    // get image as a result of a call to another page
    $('#result').attr('src', 'index.php?url=' + url + '&filter=' + filter);
});

$('#result').load(function(e) {
    $('#loader').hide(); // hide loader
});
```

See more in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).